# KSOAP2 and WSDL Returning Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am attempting to understand how to use [a SOAP webservice (link to wsdl)](http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?WSDL) with Android. I have this simple method using the ksoap2 3.0 with dependencies jar:

```
public void simpleSoap() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "";
        String METHOD_NAME = "getElement";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService";
        String URL = "http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?WSDL";

        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            Request.addProperty("elementCd","WTEQ");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error / force close each time with the response:

```
Error: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
(uri:"http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService",
local:"elementCd"). Expected elements are <{}elementCd>
```

I have tested this on a [wonderful online client](http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov%2FawdbWebService%2Fservices%3FWSDL&_ArraySize=2) and do get results. What am I missing here? Why can't I get the results for this simple elementCd WTEQ I hard coded into the addProperty function?

Answer (score 1):

After three weeks I stumbled upon this question: https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/2805758

This is because the expected namespace must be an empty String. So just make sure to put "" in the namespace when adding your property to the request.

You might also want to add a thread policy before creating the request.

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("", "elementCd","WTEQ");
```

Comment: whoa! nice to see this is coming up for folks :) I have since moved on... but thanks for putting in an answer here.